# Create pairs from a column without repeating values

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is an example.
There is a column called country which holds five values.
I want to create pairs containing two countries. The two countries are not repeated in another pair. 
for example
(India,India) is invalid.
(India,Pak) and (Pak,India) can't come twice. either one of the pair is valid.
I am using MysqlV5.7

**Country**

```
India
china
eng
pak
```

**output pairs**

```
India,china
India,eng
India,pak
china,eng
china,pak
eng,pak
```

Comment: What is your question and what have your tried?

Comment: What's your mysql version?

Comment: *(India,Pak) and (Pak,India) can't come twice* but in your expect output it comes twice

Comment: Edited the question.. If its difficult to achieve in mysql, let me know the idea or logic to get this done

Comment: @TomG check my updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `JOIN`

```
select CONCAT_WS(',',t1.Country,t2.Country) AS PAIRS
FROM  
test t1
JOIN
test t2
ON t1.Country!=t2.Country AND t1.Country<t2.Country;
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8pqLwawmwmqkYB264VpDrS/1)

Comment: you can check here http://www.complexsql.com/complex-sql-queries-examples-with-answers/  also lots of questions available on different sites google it :)